Flutter relaese.apk has bugs and debug doesn't
I've seen other people face this issue too but nothing that worked for them works for me or it's outdated. I am far in building a flutter app and this issue just started happening recently, and it is about how home page in the app rebuilds.
This bug now only appears in release.apk and happens after home page is rebuilt.
This is the initState function in home page:
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    updateLastOpenedDate();
    hasHabits();
    openCategory();

    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        context.read<HabitProvider>().setTagSelected("All");
        context.read<HabitProvider>().chooseMainCategory();
      });
    });
  }


I fixed this issue once by adding SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){}) to these functions that build the home page to stop it from happening when the home page is building but only after home page is built.
This worked and then after a few more updates to the app it happens only if the home page is rebuilt, but when you run the app fresh everything is fine until you add another habit to the list that is displayed on the home page (it's a habit tracker app) or edit a habit on the list, or anything that causes the whole home page to rebuild.
I've tried building the app using --split-per-abi and --no-shrink but the issue persisted.
All other options, such as putting the property minify to false, do not apply because I don't have those options available in my build.gradle files as it was mentioned so I think they are outdated.
Has anyone had problems like these and maybe knows how can I fix this?
